# Django form missing

Tags: django, forms, authentication

So I'm trying to make a form to appear after the user is authenticated. When the user authenticated then the form appears on the home page but it never appears. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong either in paths or view but can't figure this out. When I do the same code to external new template it works fine but I want the form to appear on the same page. Here is the code:

views.py

```
def vpn(request):
    
    form = vpn_form(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    
    context ={
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'loginas/home.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  # /
  path('', views.home, name='home'),
  # TEMPORARY
  path('signin', views.sign_in, name='signin'),
  path('signout', views.sign_out, name='signout'),
  path('callback', views.callback, name='callback'),
  path('', views.vpn, name='vpn'),
```

models.py

```
class VPN(models.Model):
    name      =        models.CharField(max_length=125)
    surname     =        models.CharField(max_length=125)
    description =        models.TextField()
    date_to     =        models.DateField()
    date_from   =        models.DateField()
```

forms.py

```
from .models import VPN

class vpn_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = VPN
        fields = ('name', 'surname', 'description', 'date_to', 'date_from')
```

home template

```
    {% extends "loginas/layout.html" %}
    {% load static %}
    {% block content %}
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="d-flex justify-content-center"> </h1>
      <p class="d-flex justify-content-center"></p>
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
   
          <form>
            {{form.as_p}}

          </form>

     {% else %}
         <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
         <a href="{% url 'signin' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-large ">Login</a>
     </div>
  {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

And the page just loads empty no form present no errors in the console. Any help how to do this would be great

Comment: you can check django documentation about forms https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/

Comment: in your views.py `if request.POST: 
        if form.is_valid(): ` is missing

Comment: You may also want a closing div for your container class after endif, before the endblock.

Comment: and your closing form tag is missing a ">"

Comment: Your URL conf is assigning views.vpn to the same url as views.home. Are you including the form in views.home?

I'm not entirely certain how django handles duplicate url patterns, or the order of precedence so this could not be the issue.

Comment: In this case I would check for user authentication via `request.user.is_authenticated` in the home view, then modify the context parameters accordingly. If the user is authenticated, then add the form to the context. If not, don't add the form. Then in the template check if the form is in the context to be displayed

Comment: The method mentioned by @plum 0 is the most convenient  way

Comment: I managed to narrow the problem to be the authentication ,if I drop {% if user.is_authenticated %} form renders perfectly but authentication stops working for some reason